# How to Generalize an Informatica Mapping & Workflow?

Tags: informatica

I need to read a text file (JSON format) and load it into a database table in Informatica Developer. For only one text file and one database table, that is easy.

But now I have N different text files, hence N different database tables and their corresponding data processor transformations. The transformation logic inside the mappings is the same. Besides creating N sets of mappings and workflows for each set of text files, is it possible to create just one generalized mapping and workflow to cater for all text files? I would appreciate it if any one of you could give me a general direction for me to explore further.

Comment: if source and taregt structure same, then you can use indirect file method where you put all files in a list and then load into same table if their target is same. Now, if they have a different target then it can be challenging

Comment: Unfortunately for each source file, there is a corresponding target database table, i.e. SourceFile1 - TargetTable1; SourceFile2 - TargetTable2; etc....

Comment: Then i would say, create 1 mapping and multiple sessions+workflows - change source and target for each session. You are leveraging reusability.